# I can't use scanf in C language , If i remove scanf then i can execute the program

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I can't use scanf in C language, If i remove scanf then i can execute the program. also vs code showing code is running contineously. Also i already added path of mingw in environmental variable
please help

[you can see the issue in image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3I54.png)

I want to use scanf.

Comment: Please post the code and the error as a text, not an images.

Comment: Can you use appropriate tags. I doubt that either VS or VS Code are the actual issue here, even if they are please only tag the relevant one - they are completely different things.